# Horizontal Scroll <div> with <a> <img> items inside

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have a table which has three columns.
The third column will have multiple images which can be clicked to perform action. So, it is desired that this column should have a horizontal scroll.
So, I added a `<div>` in third column where I added multiple `<a>` tags each containing `<img>` inside.
The problem is that the div is getting extended vertically. I want it to grow horizontally.

**My code works otherwise, but doesn't with bootstrap table css.**

[View Code Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ktvgd02n/3/)

**Can someone help ?**

> I am using bootstrap in my code. But sadly bootstrap is not offering
> out of box horizontal scrolling and I tried several solutions given on
> internet, but none worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
 td div{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width:200px; // Can be replaced it with any other value
  }
```